# How to configure Internal DNS for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 services which talk to each other by ***service*.internal.custom.com**
or by ***service*.custom.com**

Their communication is internal, i.e. non of those domains are available in public.

When I migrate to kubernetes, the new names are different. They are:
***service*.default.svc.cluster.local**

How to make Kube-DNS to map 
***service*.custom.com**  to ***service*.default.svc.cluster.local**?

Answer (score 2):

The top answer on this similar question seems a good approach:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326773/how-to-change-the-cluster-local-default-domain-on-kubernetes-1-9-deployed-with-k)

Using CoreDNS to rewrite your preferred domain to the default internal one.

You could look to change the internal name itself away from the default, but that would be a more fundamental change to the whole cluster config....this approach seems much cleaner.